# c++ on low memory systems. Standard libs are using all the memory!

Tags: c++, stl, embedded, low-memory

I need to shave off as much memory as possible. I am using standard C++ with STL. The program does not do much (yet) and it still takes 960Kb [according to `top`]! The executabe size is only 64KB.

The code is 3000 lines long, I am not going to post obviously. I believe the problem is not with my code, but with the system libraries.

A single main() function (includes all my code but doesn't use it) **uses 732Kb of RAM**!
**Simple Code:**

```
int main() {
sleep(1000); //do nothing
return 0;
}
//Uses 732kb of RAM
```

My code has no global variables (apart from ones in libraries that are hidden from me).

I am using standard libraries: libstdc++ (STL), GNU libc. Also a single BSD socket and libev and the non-standard STL rope class.

Is there some memory-profiler I can run?

**Platform**: Linux 2.6.18-32, 32-bit processor, 16MB total system RAM, no swap available
**Compiler**: GCC 4
**Standard Library**: GCC's libstdc++
**Compiler Options**: -Os (no debugging symbols)

I am **not** making heavy use of templates: containers and iterators that's all. However I am making heavy use of the SGI STL rope class.

The test environment is a basic server running Linux with 128MB RAM, Pentium III 667 Mhz, CentOS 5.5, no emulation.

**UPDATE**: I am wondering if the libraries themselves (code size) are causing the problem. Doesn't shared libraries require to be loaded into RAM?

Comment: Without any code, it will be nearly impossible to tell you where to start.

Comment: No code, no good help. Please post the code (you said it's a very basic C++ program).

Comment: What is the program doing (or should it do)?

Comment: @nightcrack, it is a HTTP transparent proxy, operating with 3MB of mem available.

Comment: Which Standard Library and compiler are you using? Are you building a debug or release binary? Are you stripping symbols? Are you instantiating the STL templates with a large number of different template arguments?

Comment: What platform are you running on? Is there an OS? Which?

Comment: Are you sure it's using that memory, or are you testing in a simulator environment (or some such) where virtual/shared memory may come into play?

Comment: what's the filesize of a compiled c program ?

Comment: @fazo Irrelevant. The filesize of the compiled C++ executable is 64kb. That is very good.

Comment: I do not understand the "very low memory" part of the title.  In my experience 732k is an enormous amount of memory, 128K executable space is lots, 64k is typical, 4K is getting there and less than 1K probably merits the "very low memory" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start stripping out functionality until the memory usage goes down.  Go extreme first -- if you can replace `main` with `sleep(1000);` and your memory use is still high, look to code and static data -- anything initialized at global scope or static inside a class or function, along with template instantiations of different types and debug symbols.

**UPDATE**: Removed incorrect commentary about STL allocators.  It may apply to other compiler/STL versions (check the history if you want to see it) but it's not applicable to this question.

Be aware that `malloc`/`operator new` will often be stingy about giving free memory back to the OS, which will cause your program as a whole not to shrink its apparent usage over time; that memory will get reused throughout your program by future allocations, so it's usually not a huge issue aside from keeping your "memory use" numbers at or near their high-water mark indefinitely.

Comment: Tried the `main()` `sleep(1000)` RAM use is still 732kb!

Comment: In that case, you're looking at code size (yes, including all the shared libraries your program links to) and static data.  Note though that for most OS's a shared library load will only be in RAM once for all processes that use it; this can make memory usage numbers a little bit deceptive, but it might not help you much if your program is all you need to run.  Static linking might actually save you memory if you can get it set up, because I believe the linker can be told to discard symbols your program does not use from libraries.

Comment: This appears to NOT be the case in GCC's libstdc++ `The current default choice for allocator is __gnu_cxx::new_allocator` which frees memory after each allocation by calling `new` and `delete` http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt04ch11.html

Comment: @unixman83 Good call!  I'd read about this recently but it looks to be incorrect for the question at hand.  Updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> UPDATE: I am wondering if the
>   libraries themselves (code size) are
>   causing the problem. Doesn't shared
>   libraries require to be loaded into
>   RAM?

Bingo. On Mac OS X at least, Top includes the size of shared libraries in the physical memory usage. Only one copy of each library is resident in memory, of course.

Check the documentation for `top` for a workaround, or just chuck it and use `malloc_info()`. Be careful to find a way to account for code, stack, and global usage, though.

Comment: @unix: No, shared libraries only need to be loaded once per process. Global variables for the library get duplicated, but that isn't what's adding up to 700k+ for you. Static linking will force the code to be loaded separately for your process, leading to worse usage — how would that solve anything?

Comment: To reiterate, the same code is being counted multiple times. You should be able to create a thousand new processes and verify that the usage reported by `top` exceeds the physical memory in the system, virtual memory furthermore being nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

Get the linker to emit a link map file; you can use that to determine exactly how much statically linked code and static data space your code requires.

Stack, heap space, and shared libraries are additional to that, and are allocated at run-time.

If you have 16Mb of RAM does it really matter?  It is likley that there is a relatively large but fixed overhead, and that your overall memory footprint will not grow linearly with lines of code added.

Comment: with RAM overhead of Linux kernel and network buffering, I really only have about 1.5MB under heavy load.

Comment: @unix:  Yes well, I could say a lot on the suitability of Linux for embedded systems that would start a whole other discussion ;).  However you are lucky; my current project has 64K total RAM, 200K of code running from Flash, includes an RTOS, file-system, USB, CAN bus, two serial ports, VHF transceiver, and 13 application threads, and I currently have about *4Kb* RAM remaining.  So 1.5Mb looks like luxurious profligacy to me!

Answer (score 0):

Since the target is a linux, I would think you could learn something about the details of memory usage, particularly shared library components by looking in the maps and smaps files in /proc/{pid_number}